# ¿Por qué la traducción no es correcta con esta biblioteca en Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, librería

¿Por qué la traducción no es correcta con esta biblioteca en Python? Instalé estas bibliotecas, pero el código es bueno, pero la traducción no es tan buena. ¿Son obsoletas las librerías?

- `py -m pip install --upgrade pip setuptools wheel`
- `py -m pip install PYGOOGLETRANSLATION`
- `py -m pip install googletrans`
- `py -m pip install google_trans_new`
- `py -m pip install async_google_trans_new`
- `py -m pip install pyGoogleTranslate`
- `py -m pip install googletrans==4.0.0rc1`

**Aquí está el código de Python**

```
import os
import re
import textwrap
import html
from google_trans_new import google_translator
translator = google_translator()
 
#-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# calea catre folder-ul cu documente de tradus
fisiere_din_folder = r"c:\Folder1"
source_language = 'ro'
# in ce limba vreau sa traduc
# {'af': 'afrikaans', 'sq': 'albanian', 'am': 'amharic', 'ar': 'arabic', 'hy': 'armenian', 'az': 'azerbaijani', 'eu': 'basque', 'be': 'belarusian', 'bn': 'bengali', 'bs': 'bosnian', 'bg': 'bulgarian', 'ca': 'catalan', 'ceb': 'cebuano', 'ny': 'chichewa', 'zh-cn': 'chinese (simplified)', 'zh-tw': 'chinese (traditional)', 'co': 'corsican', 'hr': 'croatian', 'cs': 'czech', 'da': 'danish', 'nl': 'dutch', 'en': 'english', 'eo': 'esperanto', 'et': 'estonian', 'tl': 'filipino', 'fi': 'finnish', 'fr': 'french', 'fy': 'frisian', 'gl': 'galician', 'ka': 'georgian', 'de': 'german', 'el': 'greek', 'gu': 'gujarati', 'ht': 'haitian creole', 'ha': 'hausa', 'haw': 'hawaiian', 'iw': 'hebrew', 'hi': 'hindi', 'hmn': 'hmong', 'hu': 'hungarian', 'is': 'icelandic', 'ig': 'igbo', 'id': 'indonesian', 'ga': 'irish', 'it': 'italian', 'ja': 'japanese', 'jw': 'javanese', 'kn': 'kannada', 'kk': 'kazakh', 'km': 'khmer', 'ko': 'korean', 'ku': 'kurdish (kurmanji)', 'ky': 'kyrgyz', 'lo': 'lao', 'la': 'latin', 'lv': 'latvian', 'lt': 'lithuanian', 'lb': 'luxembourgish', 'mk': 'macedonian', 'mg': 'malagasy', 'ms': 'malay', 'ml': 'malayalam', 'mt': 'maltese', 'mi': 'maori', 'mr': 'marathi', 'mn': 'mongolian', 'my': 'myanmar (burmese)', 'ne': 'nepali', 'no': 'norwegian', 'ps': 'pashto', 'fa': 'persian', 'pl': 'polish', 'pt': 'portuguese', 'pa': 'punjabi', 'ro': 'romanian', 'ru': 'russian', 'sm': 'samoan', 'gd': 'scots gaelic', 'sr': 'serbian', 'st': 'sesotho', 'sn': 'shona', 'sd': 'sindhi', 'si': 'sinhala', 'sk': 'slovak', 'sl': 'slovenian', 'so': 'somali', 'es': 'spanish', 'su': 'sundanese', 'sw': 'swahili', 'sv': 'swedish', 'tg': 'tajik', 'ta': 'tamil', 'te': 'telugu', 'th': 'thai', 'tr': 'turkish', 'uk': 'ukrainian', 'ur': 'urdu', 'uz': 'uzbek', 'vi': 'vietnamese', 'cy': 'welsh', 'xh': 'xhosa', 'yi': 'yiddish', 'yo': 'yoruba', 'zu': 'zulu', 'fil': 'Filipino', 'he': 'Hebrew'}
destination_language = 'be'
```

puedes encontrar el código completo aquí  https://pastebin.com/KkZbqJWA

**Esta es la diferencia en la traducción:**

por ejemplo, tengo esta línea en inglés: "Show the superiority of your conscience, by removing the destructive influences of your own feelings' oscillations."

con https://translate.google.com/ se traduce bien, la siguiente manera:

`Muestre la superioridad de su conciencia, eliminando las influencias destructivas de las oscilaciones de sus propios sentimientos.`

pero con PYTHON, ...google_trans_new import google_translator ... se traduce un poco peor

`Muestre la ventaja de usar sumas, emitiendo los efectos destructivos de sus propios sentimientos de peso.`

Comment: Deberías al menos incluir un ejemplo de la traducción incorrecta, con su correspondiente traducción buena.

Comment: Yo corregí. Agregué el error de traducción.

Comment: No sé qué hace el código que has pegado, pues no guarda mucha relación con el ejemplo quepones al final. Pero puedo decirte que acabo de probar a hacer un `pip install  google_trans_new` (la única que hace falta de todas las que has puesto al principio), y seguidamente he invocado `translator.translate(txt, lang_tgt="es")` siendo `txt` el que proporcionas al final ("Show the superioriity...") y el resultado obtenido ha sido exactamente el mismo que el que dices obtener con la web de translate (es decir: "Muestre la superioridad de su conciencia,..."). O sea, no he reproducido tu problema.

Comment: puedes encontrar el código completo aquí  https://pastebin.com/C4tPmfRv  Copie un archivo html en la ruta del código y pruébelo. Puedes cambiar el idioma `source_language = 'ro'` and `destination_language = 'be'`